# UILabel in UITableViewCell clips content when moved in Interface Builder

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, interface-builder

I have a UILabel inside a UITableViewCell in the latest version of Xcode. I dynamically add text to it with some line breaks and it automatically adjusts which in turn adjusts my table cell height. So long as I leave the UILabel alone in Interface builder, it all works fine. IfI attempt to move it just 1 pixel to the left or right, the content gets clipped down to a single line of text and every other line that is in the line is not viewable. It's actually pretty ridiculous. I've tried every setting for the label, but if I move it any, it clips all but the first line. Does anyone have any idea of anything else to try? I know it sounds pretty ridiculous.

```
- (CGFloat)heightForRowInInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation     {
    CGFloat width = (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait ||         interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) ?    kDescriptionLabelWidthPortrait : kDescriptionLabelWidthLandscape;
    CGFloat height = [[self descriptionString] sizeWithFont:_descriptionLabelFont constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(width, MAXFLOAT)].height + kDescriptionLabelPadding;
 return MIN(MAX(height, kMinCellHeight), kMaxCellHeight);
```

}

```
#define kDescriptionLabelWidthPortrait 429.0f
#define kDescriptionLabelWidthLandscape 685.0f
#define kDescriptionLabelPadding 50.0f
#define kDescriptionLabelFontName @"Helvetica"
#define kDescriptionLabelFontSize 14.0f
#define kMinCellHeight 44.0f
#define kMaxCellHeight 2009.0f
```

Comment: Can you share the code where you set up the label and its dynamic text?

Answer (score 1):

i am not sure but try unchecking use autoLayout for your xib file in identity and type section.

Comment: Great thought. I tried that and just tried it again to make sure. Same result. It's just nuts that something so simple as moving the label in the slightest causes this behavior.Thanks though...

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the label's number of lines to 0.  0 allows as many lines as the label wants.

Comment: Did you set the line break mode? You probably want word wrap.

Answer (score 1):

This is going to help you, this a the Code from the `CustomCell.m`

```
- (void) updateWithComment:(Comment *) comment
{
    self.aComment = comment;

    [self.userBtn setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",comment.user.firstName,comment.user.lastName] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    CGSize size =  [aComment.text sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14.0] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(210, 999)];

    [self.textLbl setFrame:CGRectMake(textLbl.frame.origin.x, textLbl.frame.origin.y, 225, size.height)];

    [self.textLbl setText:aComment.text];
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting XCode and your Mac, creating another UILabel, and changing its frame.